# Drawing lines with an arrow in the middle

Tags: c#

First of all sorry for my English...
I would like to draw lines with arrows in the middle in c#. How can i do it?

I have done this:

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
p.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
p.EndCap = LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
g.DrawLine(p, StartX, StartY, EndX, EndY);
p.Dispose();
```

But it's not enough... I would like to draw the arrow to the line's middle...

Comment: Are you saying you want it to look like `---->----` instead of `-------->`? Maybe you should add an image to your question to clarify.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question.  I went ahead and edited the title to get the tag out of it.  Please check the meta discussion ["Should tags be included in question titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)  The general consensus is "No, they should not."

Answer (score 1):

try this maybe it helps

```
  AdjustableArrowCap bigArrow = new AdjustableArrowCap(5, 5);
   Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue, 1);
   p.CustomEndCap = bigArrow;
   e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, 20, 20, 100, 100);
```

Comment: "look like ---->---- instead of -------->"
Yes, it's correct.

`AdjustableArrowCap bigArrow = new AdjustableArrowCap(5, 5);
   Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue, 1);
   p.CustomEndCap = bigArrow;`
   e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, 20, 20, 100, 100);"
It's good: sizeable arrow. But it doesn't help for me, and it would be very important, to solve this problem.

Comment: yep you can do it please refernce to this sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536325(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I can't do that Cold Tod. And i can't explain, what is my problem, but i think, i have with that "inset"... Smbdy can finish my code to work in this way pls?
---->----